# Powershell - read between multiline from a text file

Tags: powershell

as I quite new to powershell programming. However I would like to accomplish the below task with Powershell. I am having some issue trying to do a baseline checking based on some key words config block (multiple ones) from a file. I only manage to extract out the text between the "interface" and "!" with the code below:

Current code:

```
$fileContent = Get-Content C:\configs\configfile.txt -Raw
$fileContent | Select-String '(?smi)interface GigabitEthernet([^!]+!)' -AllMatches |
%{ $_.Matches } |
%{ $_.Value }
```

configfile.txt

```
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
 description connected to router
 no cdp enable
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/2
 description connected to switch
!
 interface GigabitEthernet1/0/3
 no cdp enable
!
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
```

baseline matching criteria:

```
$baseline = @("description", "no cdp enable")
```

expected result:

```
******Missing config*****
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/2
 no cdp enable
!
******Missing config*****
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/3
description
!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a regular expression trying to match an entire block, I suggest you'd use a state machine and process line by line.

1. for each `interface GigabitEthernet` line, create a new `$entry` object. Initialize everything to false.
2. if a `description` line is found, set its `$entry` property to true
3. if a `no cdp enable` line is found, set its `$entry` property to true
4. if the closing `!` is found, output the `$entry` object to the stream
5. filter all resulting objects on either description or cdp property being false.

**Example**

```
@"
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
 description connected to router
 no cdp enable
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/2
 description connected to switch
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/3
 no cdp enable
!
"@ -split "`r`n" | % {
    switch -Regex ($_) {
        "interface GigabitEthernet" {$entry = [PSCustomObject]@{interface = $_;hasDescription = $false;hasCdp = $false}}
        "description"               {$entry.hasDescription = $true}
        "no cdp enable"             {$entry.hasCdp = $true} 
        "!"                         {$entry}
    }    
} | ? {($_.hasDescription -eq $false) -or ($_.hasCdp -eq $false)}
```

Applied to your file, this would be

```
$results = switch -File C:\configs\configfile.txt -Regex {
    "interface GigabitEthernet" {$entry = [PSCustomObject]@{interface = $_;hasDescription = $false;hasCdp = $false}}
    "description"               {$entry.hasDescription = $true}
    "no cdp enable"             {$entry.hasCdp = $true} 
    "!"                         {$entry}
} 
$results | ? {($_.hasDescription -eq $false) -or ($_.hasCdp -eq $false)}
```

Comment: Hi Lieven, this is what I'm looking for. thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi Lieven I tried your provided method, somehow if the list are very long (more than 80+ line of interfaces, rest of the result are correct except when it reach last interface it will give me an repeated incorrect result. do you have any idea?

last few interfaces output of the configfile.txt

## configfile.txt

```
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/47
 no cdp enable
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/48
 no cdp enable
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/1/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/1/2
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/1/3
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/1/4
!
```

output result for GigabitEthernet2/1/4 repeated with incorrect result:

`interface                       hasDescription hasCdp`

```
---------                       -------------- ------
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/47          False   True
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/48          False   True
interface GigabitEthernet2/1/1           False  False
interface GigabitEthernet2/1/2           False  False
interface GigabitEthernet2/1/3           False  False
interface GigabitEthernet2/1/4            True  False
interface GigabitEthernet2/1/4            True  False
interface GigabitEthernet2/1/4            True  False
interface GigabitEthernet2/1/4            True  False
interface GigabitEthernet2/1/4            True  False
interface GigabitEthernet2/1/4            True  False
interface GigabitEthernet2/1/4            True  False
```

Comment: I don't know why it fails at your end but using your input in [TIO](https://tio.run/##lZFRS8MwFIXf8yvuQgX3UOvmYIIMClN8nOiDDyIzze7WSE1CcsuU2t9eW1fppozieQjk5nznhMSaLTqfYpaF0jisqpgzpQndWkiEW7URiaIbStFppHF0Hk2mDLQBubKAWiQZskEPcPkvYBSN@gzjPsNFn2FSG3gMobeZIuAvmsMnnEDBoJbfKpIphPe4wXc4DZbD9qARP5rLoQhQk/uAGTzdPcxzT@ZtkbyipOe46LAZBMurVPhr9NIpS8roZrYWmcdmPq8f6mdfll3xqvNzOFRbfPY3lVyOexkH/8CPZbQ3@Gahgwe/a/fgR6cIw0VONifYJe1qy2ZhZVV9AQ) works.